# OSS 32 bit AAC decoder

Tags: 32bit-64bit, aac

Is there an SS AAC decoding library that doesn't use 64-bit ints and is fixed-point?  Basically "MAD for AAC".  I'm coding in C++ for the Newton which is based on a StrongArm 110.  I have library code for handling 64-bit integers, but would prefer a library that was 32-bit.

Comment: No idea whether they use 64-bit integers, but have you tried [FAAD2](http://www.audiocoding.com/faad2.html) and [libavcodec](http://ffmpeg.org/) (FFMPEG)?

Comment: Yes - that's what I'm looking at now. It has references to uint64_t everywhere.

Comment: ah..  I hadn't looked at the ffmpeg lib. I don't think so, as it has inlined assembly that Newton Tools doesn't support, at least not without a lot of work. Even then, the asm looks like it uses a lot of combine multiple-add operations (ie SMLABB) which aren't supported by the SA-110.